# readonly attribute not working in text input

Tags: jquery, html

I include date picker in inputbox with readonly attribute.
But my datepicker is working but my text input replaced with date which I choose.
I just want to display the calender not to display in text box.

```
html
    <input type="text" name="f" id="datepicker" size=18 maxlength=50 style="background-color:transparent;border:0px solid white;" readonly value="hello">

css
  <script>
  $(function() {
  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
  </script>
```

Comment: you don't want the selected date to replace the textbox value?

Comment: ya I don't want the selected date in text input

Comment: I dont know how to include date picker in anchor tag.so I try this in text box

Comment: have you tried the below answers ? first one looks good.

Comment: ya i tried but I want to display it in onclick event

Answer (score 0):

`Datepicker` overrides the `readonly` property. Most robust way to achieve this is.

```
var onShowValue;

$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    beforeShow: function (input, inst) {
        if ($(input).prop("readonly")) {
            inst.dpDiv = $('<div style="display: none;"></div>');
        }
        onShowValue = $(input).val();
    },
    onSelect: function (date) {
        if ($(this).prop("readonly")) {
            $(this).val(onShowValue);
        }
    }
});
```